# Calculating the deflection of an electron in a given magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have been stuck on this question for some time but I am not able to solve it. It is a question from "Concepts of physics" (2nd volume) by H.C. Verma.

> An electron is projected horizontally with a kinetic energy of $10\,\mathrm{keV}$. A magnetic field of $1.0\times10^{-7}\,\mathrm{T}$ exists in the upward direction. (a) Will the electron deflect towards right or left? (b) Calculate the sideways deflection of the electron traveling through $1\,\mathrm{m}$. Make appropriate approximations.

I got the first part correct, by the right hand rule, $\vec v\times \vec B$ is toward right and the electron has negative charge so it goes towards left.

I tried the question in two ways. *First way*: I assumed the velocity does not change much while deflecting and calculated the acceleration as $a=\frac emvB$ used the formula $s=\frac12at^2$ to get the sideways deflection. I got the value 0.148 mm, but the answer in the book is 1.5 cm. *Second way*: Since the electron will move in a circle, it will be deflected by an angle $\theta$ and the sideways deflection will be $r(1-\cos\theta)$. Using $r=\frac{mv}{eB}=\frac{\sqrt{2mK}}{eB}$ I got $r\approx3.3\,\mathrm{km}$ and so I calculated $\theta$ which was about $2.2\times10^{-4}\,\mathrm{rad}$ and on caculating $r(1-\cos\theta)$ I again got the same value which I got in the first way.

I have checked all calculations with a calculator and it seems like there is something wrong with the method. What's the correct method for doing this and where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).